# Templates not found Django

Tags: python, html, django, web, backend

I was trying  this project mentioned in  "Lightweight Django_ Using REST, Websockets & Backbone [Elman & Lavin 2014-11-13]"  but in this i got stuck when my templates are not found can anyone help in this

my settings are

```
import os
import sys

from django.conf import settings
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', 'on') == 'on'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY',
 '%jv_4#hoaqwig2gu!eg#^ozptd*a@88u(aasv7z!7xt^5(*i&k')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
settings.configure(
 DEBUG=DEBUG,
 SECRET_KEY=SECRET_KEY,
 ALLOWED_HOSTS=ALLOWED_HOSTS,
 ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ),
 INSTALLED_APPS=(
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ),


 TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
 ),
 STATICFILES_DIRS=(
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
 ),
 STATIC_URL='/static/',
)
```

my views are

```
def index(request):
    example = reverse('placeholder', kwargs={'width': 50, 'height':50})
    context = {
    'example': request.build_absolute_uri(example)
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)



#and urls are

urlpatterns = (
 url(r'^image/(?P<width>[0-9]+)x(?P<height>[0-9]+)/$', placeholder,
 name='placeholder'),
 url(r'^$', index, name='homepage'),
)
```

and my template order in the folder is

```
 - foo    
 -     templates
 -          home.html
 -     static       
 -          site.css
```

[click for Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiQV6.png)

Comment: can you share the error message please?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your project root and directory info:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your settings,

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
 ),
```

Django is looking for template within `<PROJECT_DIR>/templates`. However, it looks like you have the template within the `foo` app, if I am not wrong.

So, you want to tell Django to also look into your apps. Please take a look into [template settings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#configuration). You may need to `APP_DIRS: True` so that Django template engine will also look into your apps.

> When APP_DIRS is True, DjangoTemplates engines look for templates in the templates subdirectory of installed applications. This generic name was kept for backwards-compatibility.

Note: Add `foo` into your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: actually foo this the project name  and as i mentioned i am refering the above title book so over there they just made a single file and added all the file's code like (views.py ,settings.py and all the other files so in this case no app is there no mange.py just single foo.py)

Comment: @R.K.Guleria what is your django version?

Comment: i am using django 2.1.1